Javascript not running when pressing back
I've made this simple example:
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <button onclick="changepath()">setPath</button>
            <script>
                function changepath() {
                    console.log("Setting hash");
                    window.location.href = window.location.href + "#hash";
                };

                (function () {
                    console.log("Self invoking:", new Date());
                })();

                console.log("Inline:", new Date());
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>

What I want to do is navigate to an url fragment (#hash) and run a script when I click "back".
It seems to me that scripts don't run when you just set the fragment, but is it possible?

Setting the fragment doesn't leave the current page, so going "back" doesn't load it again. And therefor your JS code doesn't execute again, either. Go look into the hashchange event.
